# Reference needed for powers of semi-group generators

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, markov-chains, semigroups-of-operators

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the infinitesimal generator of a Markov semi-group. I am looking for references that study powers of $\mathcal{L}$; i.e. $\mathcal{L}^n$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

For example, if the Markov semi-group generated by $\mathcal{L}$ is contractive, is the subgroup generated by $\mathcal{L}^2$ contractive to a higher order?

Comment: I'm having difficulties to understand the question. In general, $\mathcal{L}^2$ does not generate a semigroup, as can be easily seen be considering the spectrum. Apart from this, could you please explain what you mean by "contractive to a higher order"?

Comment: @JochenGlueck- Could you give me a reference for the fact, or perhaps an example? I apologize if this question is too elementary; I don't work in this field.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{L}$ denote the generator of the heat semigroup on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. The spectrum of $\mathcal{L}^2$ is $[0,\infty)$, so $\mathcal{L}^2$ does not generate a $C_0$-semigroup.